# Copying text from Word to Python makes Escape Characters unnecessary, Why?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, ms-word

I'm new to Python and recently in a class I am taking we started the dragon realm tutorial. http://inventwithpython.com/chapter6.html I decided to go way off on my own with this little project and make a semi-long adventure story. About half way through I started pasting my text into Word. (I was using a previous adventure story I had made in flash so all the test had already been written up). I started pasting into word so I could replace ' with ' and " with \" faster, since there were a lot of them and it took up a lot of time. When I ran it I noticed something odd. The text I had copied directly from Flash had needed the backslash to show ' or " properly, but the text I had copied from Word didn't. When I ran it, the text I had copied from word would show the backslashes.

for example:

```
\”This the newbie?\” The blond asked.
\”Yep Lily,\” Rachel answered cheerfully.
```

This is what will show when I'm running it. If I take out the backslashes and run it it will print:

```
”This the newbie?” The blond asked.
”Yep Lily,” Rachel answered cheerfully.
```

But the text I copied from Flash works as it should with the backslashes, and if I were to take them out it would cause an error of some sort.

Can someone please explain to me why if I copy text from Word it makes the need for the backslash unnecessary? In case anyone was wondering I was working in Python 3.2.2 I haven't tested it in 2.7.

Answer (score 7):

Word is a terrible code editor.

The quotes were replaced by a 'fancy' quote, not the normal double-quote from the ASCII alphabet, but one from elsewhere in the Unicode standard:

```
>>> u'”'
u'\u201d'
```

My Unicode application tells me that's the RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK symbol; Word normally uses matching LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK symbols as well.

If you want to use double qoutes in your python string, simply enclose the whole string in *single* quote marks:

```
'I am a string with a double (") quote'
```

Or you can use tripple-quoting:

```
"""I am a string with both singe (') *and* double (") quotes"""
```

That way you don't have to bother with all those escapes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `\` ecapes the `"`, and python didn't finds any closing quotes in string, so it raises `EOL` error:

```
In [19]: "This the newbie\ "  #add a space after `\` and it works
Out[19]: 'This the newbie\\ '

In [20]: "This the newbie\" 
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     "This the newbie\"
                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal


In [22]: "\"This the newbie\"" 
Out[22]: '"This the newbie"'
```